# How to use sum() function with where condition in mssql?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get sum of price from database using asp.net c#.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DecryptString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cn"], EncryptionKey2));
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SUM(itemrate) from darkwight_cart", conn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foodname", "Pizza");
    conn.Close();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    subtotallbl.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    conn.Dispose();
```

This code is working fine but if i add "WHERE" condition this code not working. My code is given below.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DecryptString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cn"], EncryptionKey2));
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT foodname,itemrate (select SUM(itemrate) from darkwight_cart where foodname=@foodname)", conn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foodname", "Pizza");
    conn.Close();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    subtotallbl.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: "code not working" doesn't help us. *Why* doesn't it work? Do you get an error? What is the error? What output do you expect?

Comment: That 2nd SQL Statement doesn't even make sense. Where is the value of `foodname` coming from; there's no `FROM` in the outer query.

Comment: This code return [sum 0]. but without "where" condition this code working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sum for only one foodname

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT foodname, SUM(itemrate) itemrate 
 from darkwight_cart where foodname=@foodname  group by foodname", conn);
```

Comment: Selecting `foodname` makes no sense - we know what value was transferred to the query, so it may be removed from output. And without it GROUP BY become excess.

Answer (score 0):

You query is not well structured. please see below code.

```
SqlConnection conn = new 
SqlConnection(DecryptString 
(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cn"], EncryptionKey2));
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT foodname,itemrate, 
SUM(itemrate)[Sum] from darkwight_cart where foodname=@foodname group by 
foodname)", conn);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foodname", "Pizza");
conn.Close();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
subtotallbl.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: You'll obtain something like "the field is not in GROUP BY or aggregate function"...

Comment: Thank you, and yes it will show an error. i have updated the answer

Comment: The same error. `itemrate` field will cause it. *"SELECT foodname,**itemrate**, 
SUM(itemrate)[Sum] from darkwight_cart where foodname=@foodname group by 
foodname)"*

Answer (score 0):

For one separate `foodname` transferred into a query as a parameter:

```
SELECT SUM(itemrate) AS sum_itemrate
FROM darkwight_cart 
WHERE foodname=@foodname
```

For all `foodname`s (and then select separate values on the client):

```
SELECT foodname, SUM(itemrate) AS sum_itemrate
FROM darkwight_cart 
GROUP BY foodname
```

Answer (score -2):

SQL statement:

SELECT foodname,itemrate, 
SUM(itemrate)[Sum] from darkwight_cart where foodname=@foodname

Comment: I think you need the group by clause